# window event is not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using this function to write and display the text on the same page which is working perfectly in all browsers except "FireFox". Any Idea or helping material ?
Thanks in advance !

```
function handleEvent(myEvent) {
     myEvent = myEvent || window.event;
     var FirstTextbox = myEvent.srcElement || myEvent.which;
     var SecondTextbox = document.getElementById("companynamefield");
     SecondTextbox.value = FirstTextbox.value;
     document.getElementById("comapnynameshow").innerHTML =FirstTextbox.value;
   }
```

Comment: Try using `firebug` for firefox , it might find the problem.

Comment: Yeah I already debug. But found nothing

Comment: Not related to PHP or jQuery. I suggest you stick to jQuery event binding for cross-browser behaviour rather than possibly re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: this `var SecondTextbox = document.getElementById("companynamefield").prefix;` is a bit strange.. can you explain that you want to accomplish by that?

Comment: How are you attaching this event handler?

Comment: Sorry it was by mistake. But still it is not working.
Actually I am new to javascript. When a user type into the text filed it is also updated into the other field which is on same page. Best example is when you are posting any question to stack overflow it is also updating into the bottom "view section" too.

Comment: M doing this on Onkeypress, Onkeydown and Onkeyup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
`myEvent.which`
to
`myEvent.target`

It is not which [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.which) was pressed but which [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) was clicked you are looking for.

Make sure you are passing event in the handler if it is inline

`<... onkeyup="handleEvent(event)"...`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/NBCNA/)

Comment: M doing this on Onkeypress, Onkeydown and Onkeyup

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/NBCNA/ - note that I spelled the field ID wrong on purpose to match your name `comapnynameshow`