# Event object after clicking google marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with google maps in my app,want to use **click event object** after clicking marker. 
In normal we will pass event object in **onclick**

```
<element onclick="SomeJavaScriptCode(event)">
```

and

```
    function SomeJavaScriptCode(e){
alert(e.type)
};
```

my code is

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function (e) {
            // e is not working
            var e = window.event; // it is working fine in chrome and IE, but not working in Firefox.
        }
    })(marker, i));
```

can anyone suggest.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the event? The argument `e` passed to the callback will work in all browsers, but it's not a DOM-event, it's a [**Google-Maps-Mouseevent**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MouseEvent). `window.event` is not defined by any standard, it's IE-specific and supported by some other browsers(e.g. opera and chrome)

Comment: its just the target issue...

[hope this answer helps you...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601150/window-event-is-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: @Dr.Molle i want to use event object to know the position of the mouse in the document on click